# Overleaf like autocomplete for atom

Tags: overleaf, atom

Overleaf has this great feature where it includes user defined commands (e.g. \newcommand{\lol}{\textbf{lol}} ) into its autocomplete menu. For e.g. if I type \lo a dropdown will appear with \lol at the top. Is there a similar plugin for atom which automatically includes user defined commands in its autocomplete suggestions? This feature works with labels and citations as well, but I’ll settle for a plugin which does this just for custom commands.  Thanks in advance.